# App doesn't work on client machine for WCF service with transport security

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, ssl

I have a WCF web service and listening https with a SSL cert (not self-signed). It uses `WsHttpBinding`. On developer machine, app is working, but when I publish app, on client machine it doesn't work. There is an error when connecting to WCF.

I think client machine has to install SSL cert to trusted publishers. Or another thing else?

Comment: ***WHAT*** error is there? We cannot see and read your screen, nor can we read your mind - you'll have to **SHOW US!**

Comment: I couldn't see the error because i couldn't debug app on client machine. I asked the question ,maybe someone has experienced about that story.

Comment: Yes I've run into that